# Passing arguments to a callback function

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have this simple example. I need to pass an argument to a callback function. In this code, when I do not pass any arguments, the timer works fine and it executes the callback function after the specified time interval elapsed. But if I passed `x`, the function gets executed without waiting for 5 seconds (or whatever time specified. Can you explain how to pass an argument to the callback function?

```
var x=1;
console.log("starting the script");
setTimeout(myFunction(x),5000);

function myFunction(x)
{
    console.log("This should appear after 5 seconds");
    if (x==1)
        console.log("option 1");
    else
        console.log("option 2");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're immediately executing that function.

An alternative is wrapping it with a function declaration

```js
var x = 1;
console.log("starting the script");
setTimeout(function() {
  myFunction(x);
}, 1000);

function myFunction(x) {
  console.log("This should appear after 1 second");
  if (x == 1)
    console.log("option 1");
  else
    console.log("option 2");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is because you are actually calling the function, thats why it behaves like that.

```
myFunction(x)
```

that will trigger the function, giving you the returned value of it and [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) expects a FUNCTION instead of the RESULT OF A FUNCTION, thus you need to wrap your function with another function, so just do the following:
using ES6

```
setTimeout(()=> myFunction(x),5000);
```

or using regular JS:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    myFunction(x)
 }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `.bind()` should work.

```
setTimeout(myFunction.bind(x),5000);
```

With your approach you are executing the function immediately so that is why it does not wait for specified amount of time.

`.bind()` will add the x to the context of that function which might not be the best solution if you are considering modularity in your code otherwise this should fair for your provided code.

Comment: The first argument of `bind` is the `this` value in `myFunction`, not the first argument of `myFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add that what you are passing to the timeout really is the result of myFunction(x), which is undefined. Therefore, the timeOut will have nothing to execute.

If your myFunction(x) did return a function object, then you'd see the results of the execution of myFunction(x) immediately, and 5 seconds later that other function would execute.

There is another way to fix that. All you need is to pass a function object to timeout. If you want to avoid creating the closure, you can do this:

```
setTimeout(myFunction.bind(this,x), 5000);
```

This creates a new function object *without any free argument* that will receive *this* as context, and call myFunction(x). The context is probably  unnecessary here, but is something you really should be aware of when using setTimeout: it always takes the window as default context, so if you are calling it from inside a scope where *this* has a useful meaning and you want to conserve it, you should bind it the function to it.

Because you just bound the function, you don't actually invoke it: setTimeout thus receives a function object that it will trigger after 5 seconds. It will not pass new arguments to it, but that's ok, because you have bound the argument already.

Answer (score 0):

@Ele answer above is perfectly correct.

There is a slight nuance though.

If `var x = 1` has changed its value while `myFunction` execution was delayed with `setTimeout` you will see "option 2" on console not "option 1".
This may be desired behavior but it also may be not. It all depends on your design goals.

If you need `myFunction` execution depends on the value x had at the moment the timeout was set not at the moment `myFunction` is actually executing you will have to create a closure around `myFunction` and pass it to `setTimeout`.

Try to run following code based on @Ele example to see the difference between the two approaches.

```js
var x = 1;
console.log("starting the script");

setTimeout(function() {
  myFunction(x);
}, 1000);

setTimeout(
 closureBuiler(x)
, 2000);

x = 2;

function myFunction(x) {
  console.log("Delayed output");
  if (x == 1)
    console.log("option 1");
  else
    console.log("option 2");
}

function closureBuiler(x) {
 return function(){
  myFunction(x);
 }
}
```